# Remove columns in NatTable

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, nattable

Is it possible to remove columns from **NatTable**(not just hide) ?

There is that ***DynamicColumnExample*** in the **NatTable** examples, but i just can't seem to figure out how the deletion of a column works. If someone could explain the steps i need to go through and how it should look like, it would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like every change in the list containing columns, given to the column header data provider, is reflected somehow on the UI, even if it's not an event list.

```
public disposeColumns()
{
   columnList.clear();
   natTable.doCommand(new StructuralRefreshCommand());
}
```

Or if you have a setColumns(List columnList) method, you could just call

```
setColumns(null);
```

in the disposeColumns() method.

*This will work provided that the column header data provider is created based on columnList.*

Hope this will help someone else in search for this answer. Cheers!